# WPF Inkcanvas cann't be seen after saving

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I can write well. But WPF Inkcanvas can not be seen after saving in tablet.
but if i use another computer (not tablet), can write and see well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear.  Based on my understanding, I hope that is because the size of the tablet screen which is smaller than the desktop that makes the strokes to get hidden inside the area that was not visible on the tablet,  However, the area is visible in Desktop.

Have the `InkCanvas` inside the `Viewbox`.  I hope that will fix your issue.

```
 <Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <InkCanvas />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```